Fictional biography of a mentally ill actress
I watched this movie way back in 2004 or 2005 .Its like a fictional biography of a movie actress+comedy+tragedy.
The plot goes like this.
The movie is about an actress's life.It shows how she goes mentally sick as she climbs up in her popularity. An imaginary woman is always around her ,which has been depicted as a manipulation of her own conscious who drives her crazy.That imaginary woman is actually how she looked before she got plastic surgery but played by another actress.
The movie sometimes goes in to flash backs to show how she entered in to movie industry.How she was raped by her step-father then how the warden of her child care facility tried to do the same and later on how movie directors ,business men all get sexually attracted to her.
Her shadow imaginary woman is almost always there in the movie.
She ends up killing herself in the end may be .. but i don't remember.
It has a scene that looks like she has to give an impression of her boobs in box full of wax or something , in public .. And the moment she leans over cameras start to flash .
That's as much as i remember it. 

Can you tell us how old it was and what language it was in?

Sounds like Norma Jean & Marilyn. An HBO made for TV movie with Ashley Judd and Mira Sorvino.

yeah thats the movie ..thnx ..

@Jim If this post answers your question, then click the tick mark at the left to mark the question as resolved.
